# robust and scalable data design

Tags: database-design

I have this hobby project that I'm experimenting with and learning enterprise skills.

This is the data design:

[image]

To summarize:

- a contact can be a person or an organization
- a person can login to my app (has username/password)
- a person can create/update stuff (if it has the permissions)
- a person and an organization can be customers

I put the avatar and customer_no in the contacts table to be sure that the customer_no is unique.

Contacts have to be created first, so you do not have loose persons and organizations floating around.

It's been suggested to me that I combine `persons` and `organizations` together, but it does not feel right because these are two different types with different attributes and properties in the real world, and a person can do things that an organization never could.

Would be great if you can help me to improve this design.